# Facebook Application Dialog Feed gives error when want to share a video url in facebook

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed, access-token

When I want to share a video url like **facebook.com/video/video.php?v=ID** or **facebook.com/photo.php?v=ID** with application **access_token** (via my app) it gives this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/emcjE.png

but when I change the URL that I want to share, namely: **/video/video.php?v=** TO **/video/111video.php?v=**  or to a random url it doesnt give error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEIN0.png

why this error occurs ? Any idea ?

The url is like that :

m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fvideo%2Fvideo.php%3Fv%3D3124191863158&description=Tarkan%20Ve%20Memo%20-%20Teka%3A%29%20-%20%3A%29&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&caption=Tarkan%20Ve%20Memo%20-%20Teka%3A%29&message=&app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&sdk=2&display=touch

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can share links to on-facebook content like that - see if the debugger can reach that URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug